# Java 11 not throwing ClassCastException when casting list of HashMap to list of String

Tags: java, java-11

I was expecting ClassCastExpection when running this code in Java 11 but it executes without an issue is there an explanation for this case?

```
List<?> list = List.of(new HashMap<>());
List<String> listOfStrings = (List<String>) list;
System.out.println("List size: " + listOfStrings.size());
```

Comment: Try `System.out.println("List element[0]: " + listOfStrings.get(0));`

Comment: This is normal.  There's a reason you get a compiler warning for casts like that, and it's because strange behavior can happen, as you've observed.

Comment: Related: [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Comment: This problem is called [heap pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution).

Answer (score 6):

Java generics are erased at runtime, so that cast cannot be checked. You'll get your ClassCastException once you access a not-String from the resulting list. This is why this code generates an unchecked cast warning.